# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout' - urllib request in Python3

Tags: python, python-requests, tuples, urllib, attributeerror

I am using urllib to make a request and get some data returned:

```
queryURL = "https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query"
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'f': 'json', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'outFields': 'OBJECTID, SHAPE, CSLF_ID, Area_SF', 'returnGeometry': 'false'})
```

I don't run into any problems until here:

```
req = urllib.request.urlretrieve(queryURL, params)
```

then:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

At this point I get an error thrown - `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'.` I understand that it returning an immutable tuple because of the way I formatted the `params` variable. My question is, how do I get around it, so that I can start looking at my results?

```
jsonResult = json.load(response)
```

As requested, here is the Traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-68-cb3f46b2da76> in <module>()
----> 1 urllib.request.urlopen(req)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    515                 req.data = data
    516 
--> 517         req.timeout = timeout
    518         protocol = req.type
    519 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Comment: Can you show us the traceback, rather than just the description of the error?

Comment: OK, traceback added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that this code doesn't make any sense:

```
req = urllib.request.urlretrieve(queryURL, params)
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

[`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) makes the network request for you, saves the result in a local file, then returns "a tuple `(filename, headers)`".

You're trying to pass that `(filename, headers)` pair to [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen). But `urlopen` doesn't know what to do with that; it wants either a URL string or a `Request` object, and a `(filename, headers)` pair is neither of those.

Also, it's not clear what you'd even *want* it to do. You already fetched the request and saved the result in a file. Why would you want to fetch the same request again?

The simple answer is to just not use `urlretrieve` if you don't want it. (Especially since it's deprecated anyway…) Just do this:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(queryURL, params)
```

Also, notice that I saved the result of `urlopen` in a variable. If you don't do that, you're just making a request and throwing away the response, which isn't very useful. And `jsonResult = json.load(response)` would have given you a `NameError`, because you never created anything named `response`.

---

However, there are still (at least) two other problems with your code.

First, as the docs for [`urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) say:

> If the resultant string is to be used as a data for POST … then it should be encoded to bytes, otherwise it would result in a `TypeError`.

But you're not doing that.

Second, if you want to send url-encoded data as your POST body, you need to manually set the `Content-Type` header to say so.

Some servers will guess correctly even if you get this wrong, but that's really not something you should rely on.

---

Finally, all of this would be a whole lot easier if you just did what the top of the [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) docs suggest:

> **See also**: The [Requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

With Requests, this whole thing becomes:

```
queryURL = "https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query"
params = {'f': 'json', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'outFields': 'OBJECTID, SHAPE, CSLF_ID, Area_SF', 'returnGeometry': 'false'}
jsonResult = requests.post(queryURL, data=params).json()
```

Comment: That totally worked! I got into this problem looking at an example that was too dissimilar to my data. One last question: if I want to look at this data, what would be the best way to look at it? As there are potentially 1000's of rows (can't just `print(jsonResults)`), I was going to write to a file and do something like this: `file = open(path, 'w') for item in jsonResult: file.write(item + "\r\n")  file.close`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @gwydion93 I’m not sure what the data look like, or what format you want. Is it just an array of strings (without any newlines in them) and you want a file of those strings, one per line? If so, what you’ve written will do that—but if you have or want something different, it won’t do something different.